# How to translate a simple method that uses GKAchievement from Objective-C to C#?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, game-center

**Apple developer tutorial website has this page that shows an example of how to report multiple achievements for the local player. This method is written in Objective-C.**

**Unfortunately, I can't understand Objective-C, and I am using C# and Xamarin to develop iOS games. Would you please translate this method from Objective-C to C# ?**

```
   - (void) completeMultipleAchievements
{
    GKAchievement *achievement1 = [[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier: @"DefeatedFinalBoss"];
    GKAchievement *achievement2 = [[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier: @"FinishedTheGame"];
    GKAchievement *achievement3 = [[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier: @"PlayerIsAwesome"];
    achievement1.percentComplete = 100.0;
    achievement2.percentComplete = 100.0;
    achievement3.percentComplete = 100.0;

    NSArray *achievementsToComplete = @[achievement1,achievement2,achievement3];
    [GKAchievement reportAchievements: achievementsToComplete withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
             {
                  if (error != nil)
                  {
                      NSLog(@"Error in reporting achievements: %@", error);
                  }
             }];
    }
}
```

==========================

This is the link to that tutorial webpage on Apple website:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKAchievement_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/GKAchievement/reportAchievements:withCompletionHandler:

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

#### GKAchievement:

```
//GKAchievement* achievement1 = [[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier: @"DefeatedFinalBoss"];
var achievement1 = new GKAchievement("DefeatedFinalBoss");
achievement1.PercentComplete = 100.0;
```

#### GKAchievement Array:

```
// NSArray* achievementsToComplete = @[achievement1, achievement2, achievement3];
// Using a strongly type C# Array vs. a loose typed NSArray
var achievementsToComplete = new GKAchievement[] { achievement1 };
```

#### `GKAchievement.ReportAchievements` can be handled in ObjC-style using a completion handler:

```
//[GKAchievement reportAchievements: achievementsToComplete withCompletionHandler:^ (NSError * error)
GKAchievement.ReportAchievements(achievementsToComplete, (NSError error) =>
{
    if (error != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error in reporting achievements: {error}");
    }
    else
    {
        // Continue on a success report code path 
    }
});
```

#### Or C# Async-style via the Xamarin.iOS extended Async method:

```
//[GKAchievement reportAchievements: achievementsToComplete withCompletionHandler:^ (NSError * error)
try
{
    await GKAchievement.ReportAchievementsAsync(achievementsToComplete);
}
catch (NSErrorException error)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error in reporting achievements: {error}");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try your code in my app right away, and will get back with you soon. :-)

Comment: @Thanh Glad to hear it... happy coding... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I guess ypu could read it like this:

```
public void reportAchievement(string identifier, float percentComplete)
{
    var achievement;
    try
    {
        achievement = new GKAchievement(identifier);
    }
    finally
    {
       // do nothing
    }

    if(achievement != null)
    {
        achievement.percentComplete = percentComplete;
        GKAchievement.reportAchievements( new GKAchievement[]{achivement}, (e) => {
            if (error != nil)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error in reporting achievements: %0", error);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks great. Let me try out your code in my app right away...